# Entity framework core code first migration postgresql database privileges management

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I need to set up an automated way to manage table privileges and ownership during migration execution.

Currently, the workflow is that a developer runs database migrations using his personal account during the new version release. The issue here is that he is automatically set as the owner of newly created tables, and the owner and privileges for table access have to be changed manually afterwards. I'm looking for a way to automate this, but could not find a solution. My assumption is that this is not supported by ef core as permission/ownership handling differs on underlying database used, but I don't see a reason for specific ef providers not to have this functionality. I'm probably missing something obvious and any help would be appreciated.

We are using .NET 5 with EF Core 5.0 with Postgresql.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?